# StringBuilder AppendLine method not adding the line break to HTML output

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I am using `StringBuilder` to create a content and using `AppendLine()`. But when i am showing this in a `div` content in my web page it is not coming in separate lines.

My code is like this.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(...)//my loop
{
 sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Content {0} ",myvalue))
}

return sb.ToString()
```

This result is rendering on grid

Comment: It's not a `StringBuilder` issue. HTML reduces multiple whitespaces (including newlines) into single spaces. Try add paragraphs or HTML line breaks (`<br/>`) instead.

Comment: Use `sb.Append("Content ").Append(myvalue).Append(" <br/>");`